# Control over array with bitmap

Tags: c, memory, bitmap, byte

I've now created an array with 64 spots for 8-byte blocks.
How do I implement a bitmap that checks if these spots are used?
I created the array with 64spots with this uint64_t array[64]

Answer (score 0):

Since this is (untagged) homework, I won't give code, but:

First: what's a bitmap? It's using the values of individual bits in a variable individually, rather than interpreting the value as a whole. So, if you need a bitmap to indicate which of 64 blocks are in use, you would need 64 bits - a 64-bit type would do well for this. If you need a bitmap for each of the individual bytes in a "block", the same idea holds, but you can use a smaller size map (one byte bitmap) and more of them, obviously.

Then, you need to access each bit individually - there are bitwise operators that make this easy. Bit 0 would indicate the state of block 0 (unset, or 0 = unused, 1, or set = used), bit 63 would indicate the state of block 63. A bitwise AND between a value that has the bit of the block you'd like to check, and the bitmap, will return whether that block is being used. It can be easy to visualize bits in a data type by opening up calculator programs and setting them to "programmer" mode.

Setting a bit is easy - you can bitwise OR the set bit. Unsetting is a bit trickier if you're not familiar with it, but easy once you've grasped the concept of bitwise operations.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are numbering the bits 0 .. 4095.

Then 6 bits represent the index into the bitmap bytes and 6 bits represent the bit within the array element.

if you have

```
   unsigned int bit ;
```

then

```
   unsigned int index = (bit >> 6) & 63 ;
   uint64_t mask = 1 << (bit & 63) ;

   if (array [index] & mask)
          // bit is set
```

Comment: array[] holds data - the bitmask would be separate from that, indicating which values in array[] hold valid data. So mask shouldn't be bitwise AND'ed with array[]. I did not downvote you however.